# how to stop the previous video and play a new video in recyclerViewAdapter

Tags: java, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, android-videoview

I have an arrayList of videos, displayed on screen using viewPager2 and recyclerViewAdapter, the problem is when I switch to a new video, the previous one keep playing in background, how to stop all videos and keep only the displayed one playing?

```
public class DisplayAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DisplayAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private final Context context;
    private final ArrayList<Media_class> gallery;

    public DisplayAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Media_class> gallery) {
        this.context = context;
        this.gallery = gallery;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public DisplayAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.display_adapter, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull DisplayAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        String filePath = gallery.get(position).getMediaPath() + gallery.get(position).getMediaName();
        String ext = filePath.substring(filePath.lastIndexOf("."));

        if (holder.videoV.isPlaying())
            Toast.makeText(context, "played", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //this Toast didn't displayed at all, because the new instance of video view is always stop at the beginning
        holder.videoV.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(filePath));
        MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(context);
        holder.videoV.setMediaController(mediaController);
        mediaController.setAnchorView(holder.videoV);
        holder.videoV.start();
        holder.frame_video.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.photo_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return gallery.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        FrameLayout frame_video;
        VideoView videoV;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            frame_video = itemView.findViewById(R.id.frame_video);
            videoV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.videoV);
        }
    }
}
```